# Is it if I ever lost or lose

Tags: past-participles

I'm wondering if the following sentence from this meme is correct

> Thinking if I ever lost my favourite person person

When I sent it to someone, they were like "Shouldn't it be lose instead of lost?" So is it correct to say "If I ever" followed with a past participle

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The word "ever" signals that we are talking about either all past time ending now or all future time starting now.

In the case that you cite in your question, the speaker is talking about now and before and so the past tense is required.

In the case that you cite in your comment, the speaker is talking about now and after, so the present (or future) is required.

Under no circumstance would a perfect participle like "done" be used.

Comment: I got confused. Since, you could say "If I ever do something bad stop me"  vs "If I ever done something bad stop me". The former is the correct version even though do is present simple

Comment: OK Semi-valid point. I shall edit my answer.

Comment: I suppose I understand why "do" is the correct version, and I'm almost grasping the difference. But I'm confused as in why the case in my question is "now and before". Shouldn't it be "now and after" too. Since the meme implies that if they were to lose that favourite person at any point of the future.